# What's the difference between call and execute?

Tags: vimscript

E.g., in this snippet

```
    if words[0] == "\"spellgood:"
      call remove(words, 0)
      for word in words
        execute "silent spellgood! " . word
      endfor
    endif
```

taken from "[The first and last 5 lines of a file? Use for file specific spell ignore list?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/the-first-and-last-5-lines-of-a-file-use-for-file-specific-spell-ignore-list/6542?s=1|0.1230#6542)"

Comment: `call` calls a function, `execute` executes an `ex` command.

Comment: Can you please elaborate and make this into an answer? Credit where credit is due.

Comment: I try to avoid posting answers these days, because I disagree with SE's new licence policy.  As for `call` vs. `execute`, you can get more information from the manual: `:h call()`, `:h :exe`.

Comment: @SatoKatsura wasn't the policy change postponed? And doesn't the new policy only affect code? I'd say your answer wouldn't have much code in it in this case?

Comment: @muru The fact that this issue exists to begin with is ample proof that some level of mutual trust between SE and regular posters needs to be re-established.  In my book, the way the issue was handled by SE is not conductive to that.  I don't know about you, but posting to SE is not exactly the goal of my life.  I'd say SE needs reasonably qualified posters, rather than the other way around. _shrug_

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described in `:help call`, `call` is for invoking a built-in or user-defined *function*. It's useful to use `call` if you're invoking a function without the intention of capturing the return value, because of how vim's scripting works. That is, if you have a function `foo` that returns an integer, you *must*:

```
call foo()
```

to call `foo` without caring about the result, whereas:

```
let result = foo()
```

can be used to call `foo` and put the result in `result`. Note how `call` is *not* required for the second example. `call` also can take a range, which has the effect of invoking the function for every line in that range, usually.

`:help execute`, on the other hands, reveals that `execute` is for evaluating strings as *Ex commands*. Normally you don't need to use `execute` in vim scripts, as most of what you type in them is interpreted as an Ex command. However, `execute` exists and is particularly useful for invoking commands built up at *runtime*, as was done in the answer you linked to in order to add a word discovered at runtime to the spelling dictionary.

Comment: Looking at it from another perspective: vimscript only runs *commands*. There's no way to directly run a function. You can use the `call` command if you want to discard the return value, `echo` if you want up print it, `let` if you want to save it, but you *have* to use a command.

Answer (score 2):

- We use a command just by writing it
- When we use a string as a command, put `execute` before the string

These 2 lines get the same output

`:echo 'hi_1'`

`:execute "echo 'hi_1'"`

NOTE
`:` indicates a `ex command`, instead of an option, motion or other things in vim  (try `:help :bar`  vs  `:help bar` )

---

(Thank @filbranden for reminding me of my mistakes. And since answers above have pointed out differences between `:execute` vs `:call`, below I add something I think useful, without repeating my revise of answers above)

### `:execute`

in vim's help

```
:exe[cute] {expr1} ..

Executes the string that results from the evaluation  of {expr1} as an Ex command.
```

When I need to give multiple commands in one  line, I usually use `|` (see `:help :bar`, not `:help bar`). When that line is complicated, I need to use `:excute` as a work around of `|`

Example of using `|` :

`: echo 'hi_1'  | echo 'hi_2'`

A real example of using `|` and `execute`:

```
autocmd BufReadPost *
     \ if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$") |
     \   execute "normal g`\"zv" |
     \ endif
```

### About `:normal`

```
:norm[al][!] {commands}                 *:norm* *:normal*
            Execute Normal mode commands {commands}.  This makes
            it possible to execute Normal mode commands typed on
            the command-line.  {commands} are executed like they
            are typed.
            This command cannot be followed by another command,
            since any '|' is considered part of the command.

            An alternative is to use |:execute|, which uses an
            expression as argument.  This allows the use of
            printable characters to represent special characters.
```

Example of representing special characters:

`:exe "normal \<c-r>"`
(redo)

### `:normal` and `bar`

`:normal` command see the '|' as a argument, and can therefore not be followed by another Vim command

`:normal gg | echo 'hi'`  can't get anything printed. It meas: under normal mode, types `gg | echo 'hi'`, where `|` is a `motion`

`:help |` (`:help bar`)

> To screen column [count] in the current line.  |exclusive| motion.  Ceci n'est pas une pipe.

"Ceci n'est pas une pipe", French for "This is not a pipe" .  (One interpretation is that the pipe in the painting is not a pipe, but rather a drawing of a pipe.)

### A real example of `:execute` (with `:normal`)

```
func Print_n()
    if &filetype == 'python'
        execute "normal yiwoprint(f'{= }')"
        execute "normal hhhhhp"
    elseif &filetype == 'cpp'
        " execute 'normal yiwocout<<""<<' | execute 'normal hhhpf<lpa<<endl;'
        execute 'normal yiwocout<<""<<'
        execute 'normal hhhpf<lpa<<endl;'
    elseif &filetype == 'zsh'
        execute 'normal yiwoecho ${}'
        execute "normal hp"
    elseif &filetype == 'vim'
        execute 'normal yiwoecho &'
        execute "normal p"
    endif
endfunc

func Print_v()
    if &filetype == 'python'
        # execute "visual y"
        execute "normal oprint(f'{= }')"
        execute "normal k$hp"
    endif
endfunc

nnoremap _p :call Print_n()<CR>
vnoremap _p :call Print_v()<CR>
```

Comment: You start by explaining that `execute` is useful to invoke commands built up at runtime... But then all your examples are using commands which are composed of a single string, so they're definitely *not* being built up at runtime (from variables, or expressions)... This is more of a case of `execute` being used to work around `:bar` (see `:help :bar`) or, maybe in most of these cases, out of an abundance of caution for possible trailing whitespace interfering with the `normal` command...

Comment: Also, while this answer gives some examples of `execute` (perhaps without enough explanation), it doesn't even try to address `call`, so it hardly answers *"what's the difference between call and execute"*...

Comment: thank you.  What about now?

Answer (score -1):

Petrie's answer is only partially true.

By partially I mean, take for example, `bdelete`. Supposedly, as stated by vim's manual, it states that by providing a number `N` identifying a buffer (as in using the number provided by `ls` or `ls!`), you can delete a buffer in vimscript. Well that is only true, if you provide a literal number, like `bdelete 6`, you will delete buffer 6. However, if you pass a variable to `bdelete` that contains the buffer number to delete like, `bdelete g:buffer_to_delete` (where `g:buffer_to_delete=6`), it will not work! In fact in vimscript you can not write `:bdelete g:buffer_to_delete` or `call bdelete g:buffer_t_delete`. However, you can treat the command as a string and execute it like so, `exec "bdelete".g:buff_to_delete`, that will work!

Thus vimscript `call` DOES NOT invoke user-defined or internal functions all the time. There are situations where `exec` must be used because `call` doesn't function as it is supposed to. This situation has been around for many years and still lingers today with vim 8.0. So be aware and follow the rule:

If you can't make the `call` try `exec`uting instead.

It is not clear when you can use `call` and when you must use `exec` for I have found the above situation occurring erratically. So start with `call` then if it fails, `exec` will work, as of yet I haven't found an instance when it doesn't, fortunately!

Note to Vimscript World: there are other nuances like the above that should be spelled out clearly in the vim documentation, or at least fixed in the vim code! I and many others I know have spent many many hours in years passed wasting time figuring out these nuances. I thought Emacs was truly terrible in this regard, but Vim too has its own undisclosed idiosyncrasies.

And before you say it....yes I have provided these issues years ago. I am only writing this now, because I feel a lot of sympathy for Yossi for going through this problem, because I had the same problem many years ago.

Yossi: keep an open mind with Vimscript it lacks quite a bit of common-sense, but if you keep your wits about yourself you can get much for your time spent on vim, than you would with say with Emacs! Trust me, I've been using Emacs and (G)Vi(m) for 30 years now. (G)Vi(m) is the way to go...Emacs is fast dying, and rightly so :-( {Hey Stallman, don't you think its time to admit Emacs sux? Why go to all the trouble and create Evil, when Vim is free?}

Keep pushing Yossi! It will pay off!
(Yes everybody, I know this reply is a year late, but I can bet you there are many other Yossi's out there)

Let's hope, Vim 9.0, will do a better job than Vim 8.0. (I hope I will be still alive to see 9.0!)

Comment: `:call` is an Ex command that can only call (sic) functions (user defined, or builtin). We use it when we don't care about the returned value. `:execute` is an Ex command that can only execute an Ex command. Vim interpreter already executes Ex commands on its own, however it doesn't permit to pass dynamic parameters to these commands. Hence `:execute`. There is also the `call()` function that eases dynamic calling of functions (dynamic name, dynamic number of parameters). In a way, `call()` simplifies what we used to do to forward calls with `execute` in Vim6 & in prior versions.

Comment: That is not quite true. `call` works perfectly fine.

Comment: IOW, we can't say that `:call` doesn't do its job. Executing Ex commands is not its job. It's `:execute` job. I won't say this isn't cumbersome. Fighting with (against?) `:exe` is really cumbersome.

Comment: `bdelete` isn't a function.

Comment: `If you can't make the call try executing instead. ` You really sound like you don't totally understand what you're talking about.

Comment: `However, if you pass a variable to bdelete that contains the buffer number to delete [..] it will not work! ` -> Yes, that is expected and totally unrelated to the asked question. Actually, Josh mentioned this in the last paragraph of his answer!